# Trying to use jQuery AJAX with Codeigniter but $.post() doesn't work properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
                    $.post("datahandler.php",{
                        UserName: name,
                        PassWord: password

                    },function(data, status){
                        alert(status);
                        $("#co").html(data);
                    });
```

So I was trying to use `$.post` but this function only worked when I set
 `datahandler.php` to `root(C:\xampp\htdocs\codeign)` itself but it failed when i  put it in `C:\xampp\htdocs\codeign\application\views\pages\datahandler.php`
 , the code but it didn't worked.

So i tried to change the `datahandler.php`  to `C:\xampp\htdocs\codeign\application\views\pages\datahandler.php` and
`codeign\application\views\pages` but it still didn't worked.

Some of my 
elders said problem is about controllers and the routes but i don't think so since my default controller points to views folder 
`("C:\xampp\htdocs\codeign\application\views")`

Here is my controller (Pages.php):

```
  public function view($page = 'JoinUs')
   {

    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
    {


            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
    if($page == "datahandler")
    {
      $this->load->view('pages/datahandle',$data);
    }
    else{

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
   }
```

}

Here is my routes.php file:

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


    $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

    $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Here is the full version of header:

```
      <html>
       <head>
             <title>Dark Site</title>
             <style>
                  body {
                 background-image: url("/images/cookie.jpg");
              }
             h1 {
                 text-align: center
             }

            </style>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
                    crossorigin="anonymous">
            </script>
            <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#login2").click(function() {
                    var name  = $("username").val();
                    var password = $("password").val();
                    $.post("datahandler.php",{
                        UserName: name,
                        PassWord: password

                    },function(data, status){
                        alert(status);
                        $("#co").html(data);
                    });
                 });



              });
             </script>        
     </head>
     <body >
             <h1><?php echo  $title; ?></h1>
                 <p style="text-align:center;"><img src="/images/vade.jpg" 
    alt="Logo"></p>
```

So i am kinda stuck, sorry if you see major mistakes i am just trying to learn this alone in an intern since they don't give me proper work.

Comment: You want to send request to a CI Controller path and have controller return what you need. Controller would load view to return

Comment: use `site_url('pages/views/datahandler')` for the proper URL path in you ajax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your configuration,

```
$.post("datahandler.php", {     
         ^
           this will not work 
})
```

You need at least

```
site_url('pages/view/datahandler')
           ^     ^            ^
    Controller   Method you   Argument, in your case view file you want to load
                 are calling
```

Correct like below

```
$.post(
       "<?php echo site_url('pages/view/datahandler');?>", 
       { 
         Username : $("username").val(), 
         Password : $("password").val() 
       },  
       function(){


       }
);
```

Comment: Thanks!  You are a legend.